# Neo4J Match & Set Multiple Relationships/Nodes in One Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm currently running the following query to update the properties on two nodes and relationships.

I'd like to be able to update 1,000 nodes and the corresponding relationships in one query.

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[r1:OWNS_CAR]->(c1:Car) WHERE id(r1) = 3018
MATCH (p2:Person)-[r2:OWNS_CAR]->(c2:Car) WHERE id(r2) = 3019
SET c1.serial_number = 'SERIAL027436', c1.signature = 'SIGNATURE728934', 
r1.serial_number = 'SERIAL78765', r1.signature = 'SIGNATURE749532', 
c2.serial_number = 'SERIAL027436', c2.signature = 'SIGNATURE728934', 
r2.serial_number = 'SERIAL78765', r2.signature = 'SIGNATURE749532'
```

This query has issues when you run it in larger quantities. Is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by running it "in larger quantities"? Please update your description to give an example of a problematic query.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with a LOAD CSV. Your input would contain the keys (not the ids, using the ids is not recommended) for Person and Car and whatever properties you need to set. For example

```
personId, carId, serial_number, signature
00001, 00045, SERIAL78765, SIGNATURE728934
00002, 00046, SERIAL78665, SIGNATURE724934
```

Your query would then be something like :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///input.csv' AS row
MATCH (p:Person {personId: row.PersonId})-[r:OWNS_CAR]->(c:Car {carId: row.carId})
SET r.serial_number = row.serialnumber, c.signature = row.signature
```

Note that you should have unique constraints on Person and Car to make that work. You can do thousands (even millions) like that very quickly ...

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We tried a LOAD CSV with a CSV file with 2k rows. Neo4j took so long we gave up.

Comment: Do you have unique constraints on the nodes (and use those to do the match) ? Can you share the LOAD CSV query that you used ? Unless you're jumping through a lot of hoops, 2k rows should be done in a couple of seconds (and that's the worst case).